# Exibir chaves estrangeiras de uma tabela na consulta

Tags: php, mysql, query, join

Tenho uma tabela onde cada `projeto` pode estar relacionado com até 4 `produtos`.

- Tabela Principal (chaves estrangeiras):

  - `IDPRODUTO`
  - `IDPRODUTO2`
  - `IDPRODUTO3`
  - `IDPRODUTO4`
- Tabela `produtos`

  - `ID`
  - `NOME`

Para realizar a exibição, criei uma tabela dinâmica. Quando faço a consulta, uso `JOIN` para trazer a tabela de produtos.

O problema é que não consigo exibir o nome dos 4 produtos, apenas o nome do produto da 1ª ID que aparece. Como faço para exibir o nome do produto relacionado aos outros ID's ?

[image: Exibição da tabela:]

Consulta MySQL:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM principal 
JOIN produto on principal.IDPRODUTO and principal.IDPRODUTO2 and principal.IDPRODUTO3 and principal.IDPRODUTO4 = produto.PROD_ID 
JOIN responsavel on principal.IDRESPONSAVEL = responsavel.RESP_ID 
JOIN  reserva on principal.IDRESERVA = reserva.RES_ID 
WHERE principal.PROJETO LIKE '%$q%'
```

PHP para exibição da tabela:

```php
 <tr>
    <td height="27"><?php echo $row_BUSCA['ID']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row_BUSCA['PROJETO']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row_BUSCA['DATA']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row_BUSCA['IDPRODUTO']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row_BUSCA['IDPRODUTO2']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row_BUSCA['IDPRODUTO3']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row_BUSCA['IDPRODUTO4']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row_BUSCA['IDRESPONSAVEL']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row_BUSCA['DESIGNADOR']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row_BUSCA['TAGS']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row_BUSCA['EQUIPAMENTO']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row_BUSCA['IDRESERVA']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row_BUSCA['ARQUIVO']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row_BUSCA['PROD_ID']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row_BUSCA['PROD_NOME']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row_BUSCA['PROD_NOME']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row_BUSCA['PROD_NOME']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row_BUSCA['PROD_NOME']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row_BUSCA['RESP_ID']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row_BUSCA['RESP_NOME']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row_BUSCA['RESPO_TEL']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row_BUSCA['RES_NOME']; ?></td>
  </tr>
```

OBS: Está bem rudimentar.. posteriormente trabalharei nos detalhes.

Grato por qualquer ajuda.

Luciano.

Comment: @dherik está certo. Pode você mostrar a definição das tabelas? E mais fácil ajudar quando podemos ver a consulta de fazer por a tabela

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa fazer um JOIN para cada FK de produto na tabela projeto para obter o nome do produto ou uma subquery. Isto pode ser feito de outras maneiras, mas apresentarei estas 2, imaginando que a coluna que contém o nome do produto na tabela `produto` seja chamada de `nome` mesmo.

Com JOIN:

```
SELECT princ.*, p1.nome, p2.nome, p3.nome, p4.nome FROM principal princ
JOIN produto p on princ.IDPRODUTO and princ.IDPRODUTO2 and princ.IDPRODUTO3 and princ.IDPRODUTO4 = p.PROD_ID 
JOIN produto p1 ON principal.IDPRODUTO = p1.IDPRODUTO
JOIN produto p2 ON principal.IDPRODUTO = p2.IDPRODUTO2
JOIN produto p3 ON principal.IDPRODUTO = p2.IDPRODUTO3
JOIN produto p4 ON principal.IDPRODUTO = p2.IDPRODUTO4
JOIN responsavel resp on princ.IDRESPONSAVEL = resp.RESP_ID 
JOIN reserva res on princ.IDRESERVA = res.RES_ID WHERE princ.PROJETO LIKE '%$q%'
```

Com Subquery:

```
SELECT princ.*, 
(select nome FROM produto where produto.id = princ.IDPRODUTO), 
(select nome FROM produto where produto.id = princ.IDPRODUTO2),
(select nome FROM produto where produto.id = princ.IDPRODUTO3),
(select nome FROM produto where produto.id = princ.IDPRODUTO4)
FROM principal princ
JOIN produto on princ.IDPRODUTO and princ.IDPRODUTO2 and princ.IDPRODUTO3 and princ.IDPRODUTO4 = produto.PROD_ID 
JOIN responsavel on princ.IDRESPONSAVEL = responsavel.RESP_ID 
JOIN reserva on princ.IDRESERVA = reserva.RES_ID WHERE princ.PROJETO LIKE '%$q%'
```

Fique atento ao mapeamento do seu banco também. O fato de você ter 4 chaves estrangeiras (*Foreign Keys*) de produto para em uma tabela pode indicar que, talvez, você precisa de uma tabela N para N entre principal e produto. Assim, se surgir a necessidade de um `IDPRODUTO5` ou tratar registros que não tem todos os `IDPRODUTO`, a distribuição de informações nas tabelas ficará mais coerente e flexível.